# How can I export to CSV in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know this question has been asked and answered in several ways, but none of them get to the crux of the matter that I need to understand.  In WebForms, we 'subvert' the rendering process and write straight to the Response's output stream.  How does one achieve that using a Controller Action, to write CSV to a file for Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same way you'd write any other file -- use FileResult and it's descendants.

Comment: Thank you, now I know how to write any other file as well.

Answer (score 4):

Just to elaborate on Omu's FileHelpers answer, I was able to combine [@shamp00's ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573853/314291) here with [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414118/314291) in order to render a CSV to a `FileContentResult` via stream on the fly.

Given a FileHelpers DTO Model like so:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")] 
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller action:

```
public FileContentResult DownloadFoosCSV()
{
     var foos = GetFoos(); // IEnumerable<Foo>

     var fileHelper = new FileHelperEngine<Foo>();
     using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
     using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
     {
         fileHelper.WriteStream(streamWriter, foos);
         streamWriter.Flush();
         return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/csv", "NewFoos.csv");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try CsvActionResult described at http://develoq.net/2011/export-csv-actionresult-for-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this: http://www.filehelpers.net/ in an asp.net mvc application, look at the getting started  guide, you should get it from there