# Writing to excel string in encoding UTF-16

Tags: python, csv, unicode, python-3.x

I'm opening text file in `encoding UTF-16` mode:

```
with open(file.txt, 'r', encoding="UTF-16") as infile:
```

Then I want to write to an excel file:

```
from csv import writer
excelFile = open("excelFile_1.csv", 'w', newline='') 
write = writer(excelFile, delimiter=',')
write.writerows([[input]])
```

where `input` is a term from the text file `file.txt`

I get the following error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 113: character maps to <undefined>
```

Using Python 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pick an output encoding for the CSV file as well:

```
excelFile = open("excelFile_1.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding='UTF16')
```

The default codec for your system cannot handle the codepoints you are reading from the input filename.

Opening this file in Excel *may* not work; do follow the procedure in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488070), picking the UTF16 codec, to ensure that Excel reads the file correctly.

You could also try using UTF-8, adding in a UTF-8 BOM to the start of the file:

```
excelFile = open("excelFile_1.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding='UTF8')
excelFile.write('\ufeff')  # Zero-width non-breaking space, the Byte Order Mark
```

It is mostly Microsoft software that uses a BOM in UTF-8 files, since UTF-8 only has **one** byte order to pick from, unlike UTF-16 and UTF-32, but it apparently makes Excel happy(er).

Comment: I tried the second option, work great with the regular open of excel, and I didn't need to add the "\ufeff".

Comment: @user1869297 it will work without the BOM until you have some actual Unicode non-ASCII characters in the file. And I know you know this Martijn, but the purpose of the BOM in this case is not to signify byte order, it's to mark the file as UTF-8 encoded instead of one of the ancient code page encodings that Microsoft still prefers.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, I know, Microsoft has to support too many legacy codecs. Note that the OP *does* have codepoints in the Latin-1 range in the output, that's why they had errors in the first place.