# Make PHP exported CSV with UTF-8 character work on mac excel using commas

Tags: php, excel, macos, csv

So I'm trying to export a `csv` using PHP in which the contents contains `UTF-8 character` and I want the resultant csv to open in Excel smoothly (including Mac excel)

So there is an answer here: [How can I output a UTF-8 CSV in PHP that Excel will read properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly)

Checkout the top answer.

But then in order to implement that you need to use tabs to separate the fields instead of commas...Is there a way to achieve this while still using commas and not tabs and still have it work in OS X

### EDIT

Mostly to Mark Baker but everyone feel free to comment

Another code update

```
while(@ob_end_clean());
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fileexport.csv");
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
print "sep=,\n";
print $output;
exit;
```

Comment: With a BOM headingto the file, and by using a `sep=,` as the first line of the file?

Comment: But simply setting http response headers to say it is UTF-8 will have absolutely no effect whatsoever

Comment: will that work with Mac OS X excel

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: will it theoretically work? i'm not gonna bother with something that's not even supposed to work in theory....also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395699/sep-statement-breaks-utf8-bom-in-csv-file-which-is-generated-by-xsl ... do you print out sep=, first or the BOM heading first...also isn't sep=, outside the csv standard?

Comment: Theoretically it will work, otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it; but I don't have a Mac that I can actually test it on

Comment: BOM should __always__ be the first bytes in the file; where sep=<x> applies, it should be the first line of the file.... and yes, it's outside the original CSV standard... the standard has evolved.... and it's not likely to work with older versions of Excel, which is why I prefer building BIFF or OfficeOpenXML files, because they never have this problem

Comment: @MarkBaker It didn't work checkout my code in the question

Comment: Why are you converting from UTF-8 to UTF-16LE? Why not simply write UTF-8 with a UTF-8 BOM?

Comment: @MarkBaker checkout the update once again....this time the outputted utf8 characters dont get converted...note that if I get rid of the print "sep=,\n" line it works...but mac isn't going to accept this

Comment: OK, you've convinced me that it doesn't work, and that I'm right to use native Excel formats rather than CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fputcsv](https://www.php.net/fputcsv) should work fine in this instance. Take the following example, where as the third parameter of `fputcsv` is the delimiter. By default it is `,` (comma), but you could also use "\t" for tab files. CSV files should be interpreted the same on either OS

```
if( $fh = fopen("output_file.csv","w") ){
    
    $put = array("column1, with comma","column2, with comma","column3" /*,"columnN"*/);
    
    fputcsv($fh,$put,",");
    
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: "CSV files should be interpreted the same on either OS" well apparently it's not checkout that SO link - also its an excel issue on Mac

Comment: and more importantly it's about outputting utf8 contents into csv