# Umlauts not displaying properly in excel despite UTF-8 header and byte order mark

Tags: php, excel, csv, utf-8

I'm writing data into a csv that somtimes contains umlauts (äöü). I used:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv;charset=UTF-8');
```

and added on the first line of data

```
chr(239).chr(187).chr(191)."SEP=\t";
```

and then filled in the data. However, even so the umlauts get displayed as e.g. `Ãœ` for `Ü` in excel on windows and something similar on mac.

Is there anything I need to do to get this right?

Comment: Use the correct ASCII table. äöü are produced by Chr(228), Chr(246 and Chr(252). When entering them from a keyboard you can use Alt+0228, 0246 and 0252.

Comment: @Variatus no. Those byte values are for the single-byte ISO8859-1 and cp1252 encodings, _not UTF8_. Simple rule of thumb, if you have a character represented by a single byte with a value above 127, it's not UTF8.

Comment: @Sammitch I don't think OP needs UTF-8 character codes in his application. I think he should use ASCII and the system will convert them to UTF-8.

Comment: @Variatus I don't even know where to start with all of the things wrong with what you've just posted.

Comment: I've reproduced this locally and the issue seems to be that when Excel sees the `SEP` specification it forgets the charset that it detected when it read the BOM. There are a couple unattractive workarounds [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395699/sep-statement-breaks-utf8-bom-in-csv-file-which-is-generated-by-xsl) but also you could simply use commas or semicolons as separators and skip the `SEP` and this issue altogether.

Comment: @Sammitch when I've used commas word on OS X would properly display the data, but not word on Windows. Another thread suggested tabs as a fix. Also, I can confirm that removing the SEP gets the umlauts right

Comment: Word? You mean Excel, yes? Anyhow, that might be a more solvable issue. I would suggest posting a new question along the lines of "CSV does not display consistently between Excel on Windows and Mac" with example data/code.