# Convert generated UTF-8 content to ISO 8859-1 on the fly in Apache

Tags: php, apache, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

We have a PHP application running on Apache which generates CSV files that are to be opened with Excel; the content is encoded in UTF-8. However, there is a problem with Excel, which does not recognise the character encoding and displays the annoying 'Ã¶' instead of 'ö', for example, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6002256/446278).

Now, since it is not possible to configure Excel to correctly recognise UTF-8 encoding, and opening the file through 'external data import' as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488070/446278) is not an acceptable for us, I thought maybe it is possible to configure Apache to use some kind of filter to convert UTF-8 encoded response to ISO 8859-1 on the fly? In this case I would not have to change any PHP scripts - they would continue to produce UTF-8 encoded content - I would just have to configure Apache to convert the output for some of them to ISO 8859-1 on the fly such that the resulting files could be opened easily with Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Actually solved it with this:

```
# beginning of file
function encode($buffer) {
    return iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $buffer);
}

ob_start("encode");

# content generated here

ob_end_flush();
# end of file
```