# unicode in panda dataframe messed up when opened in excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, unicode

I am trying to make a "results" dataframe with in each cell calculated values and their uncertainties, separated with the ± symbol. I then save the dataframe to a csv.
I've made the example below to illustrate the problem: when I open the csv with textedit (or print it to screen) it all works. However, when I open (or import) the csv in excel suddenly the ± symbol is proceeded with another symbol: Â.

I've tried to force the variable to a string using "str()" and played around with the "encoding='utf-8' " but I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong here..
I'm using Python2.7 and Komodo on a macbook air.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

PmSign = (u'\u00B1').encode("utf-8")

columns = ['A']
data = [1,2,3,4,'5 {} 3' .format(PmSign),6]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

df.to_csv(os.path.join('/Users/python/','UnicodeDFTEST.csv'), encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Are you sure Excel knows that the file is UTF-8? There should be a dropdown saying 'File origin' or something like that when you import your file. Make sure that's set to UTF. ([More info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6488070/182402))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

PmSign = (u'\u00B1')

columns = ['A']
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, u'5 {} 3'.format(PmSign), 6]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join('/Users/python/','UnicodeDFTEST.xlsx')
df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name="Sheet 1")
writer.save()
```

Comment: Cool! I did look at that but couldn't get it to work..Thanks!!

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Note the addition of the 'u' to your data line.

Answer (score 0):

As @Wander Nauta mentioned, there is a `File origin` setting. You need to use the Text Import Wizard. Try the following:

1. Start Microsoft Excel.
2. Open a blank workbook.
3. Select the `DATA` tab at the top.
4. Press the `From Text` button.
5. Choose your `UnicodeDFTEST.csv` file.
6. Under `File origin` select `65001: Unicode (UTF-8)` from the long drop down list.
7. Press `Next >`
8. Make sure the correct delimiter is used.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but if I do that, the ± sign disappears completely. Also, I was hoping for a Python-fix so I can dubbelclick the csv file to open (which is much easier/faster).
Currently I do that and then replace the extra symbol by a space which works but is a bit silly imo.

Comment: You could consider using a different Python library to write your file directly in xlsx format thus avoiding any possible CSV conversion issues. I have not tried that with UTF-8 format yet.