# store gujarati data from csv to MySQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Following code which is used to browse csv file.
Fatch data from csv and store in a MySQL database.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        કેમ છે: <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php
    include ("connection.php");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 0;
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $name = $filesop[0];
            $marks = $filesop[1];
            mysql_query("set name utf8");
            $query = "INSERT INTO temp (name, marks) VALUES ('".$name."','".$marks."')";
            echo $query;
            $sql = mysql_query($query);
        }
    }
?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Following code is used connect database.

```
<?php

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "test";
    $conn = mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("$database", $conn) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

When I run code its stored data like "????????".

My CSV file like below

[image]

Following phpmyadmin version information

[image]

Following is my table structure

[image]

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6488070/946170

Comment: @imdad i want to import using php programming not directly

Answer (score 1):

if you're getting stored *????????* in database, then,

You need to check the `database collation` first, change it to `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8mb4_general_ci` if simple `utf_general_ci` doesn't work.

Second, if `collation` is fine then it could also be possible that string is already in `utf8` format, and you're converting it forcefully again.

Use following function to convert string to `utf8`.

```
function convToUtf8($str){ 
    if( mb_detect_encoding($str,"UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, GBK")!="UTF-8" ) 
        return  iconv("gbk","utf-8",$str);
    else
        return $str; 
}
```

Then in your code

```
while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
{
    $name = convToUtf8($filesop[0]);
    $marks = convToUtf8($filesop[1]);
    //mysql_query("set name utf8");   No need to do this now
    $query = "INSERT INTO temp (name, marks) VALUES ('$name','$marks')";
    echo $query;
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
}
```

and look here and set db `collation`
[image]

Comment: what is your database `collation`?

Comment: and specifically, what is table's `collation`?

Comment: some problem regarding in CSV when i save and close CSV file with UTF-8 format and reopen CSV it display "????" data

Comment: problem with csv file than, ot with DBMS, you need to store it in excel and get it from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93911/discussion-between-magento-learning-phase-and-mubin).