# Downloaded csv files contains ??????? in the place of some arabic letters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

Here is my code for initiating download

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.HeaderEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8;
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "none");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment" + "; filename=Data.csv");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
        args.AbortPipeline();
```

the out csv file contains like this at the place of some arabic letters

**Data**
99999;Arabic: ?????????????? ?????????????? al-abj;jkj;biluruya@mswork.ru;

I dont know why the UTF-8 encoding is not working here or is my download code wrong . could some one pls explain me the issue here ?

Thanks

Comment: Try this
`Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Data.csv")`

Comment: Append header and add header are both same, my problem here is the encoding...

Comment: May be problem is not in the writing, it can be in reading file. Try opening the CSV file using a text editor like Notepad++. Select in the Encoding menu UTF8.

Comment: Also can you update you code to understand how you get buffer? May be buffer can contain wrong encoding.

Comment: buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvfile.ToString());                                             this is my buffer which i am encoding and this currently works in notepad and i can able to see the arabic text. But when i open the same file in excel the arabic text is showing like special characters ? pls help

Comment: You could google for importing csv into excel with special characters. You will find some information, a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically

Comment: Resolved the issue by adding utf8 preamble