# How to encode strings with mixed character sets for Excel in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, utf-8

I'm trying to encode some nested lists of data in python in order to save the file as a csv and have others be able to access and use the data in Excel.

My data is supplied in `UTF8`. As part of converting this into an Excel-friendly format, I typically decode from `UTF8` and encode using `cp1252` so that Excel can display the csv data correctly.

If the data is in Russian, I would use `cp1251` instead, for the windows/excel-friendly Cyrillic character set.

However, I have issues with string which are a mixture of character sets.

If we take a string `asdasdasd фоиииффииф`, is it possible to encode this in a manner that will allow me to save a csv that can be opened in Excel? It's not a problem in `UTF8` of course, but I can't use that for opening in Excel...

Comment: First of all, there is nothing preventing a CSV file from containing UTF-8 data. (If you are using Python 2, then you do have to work around some limitations with its `csv` module, but that is doable. And there is no trouble with Python 3.) Second, if the data will be opened in Excel, you can write directly to an Excel workbook. I strongly recommend XlsxWriter for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by ignoring Windows codecs and instead keeping UTF8, and inserting a BOM. I believe my original question had no solution using Windows codecs.

[Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)