# Cyrillic Alphabet to English or Latin

Tags: excel, utf-8, transliteration, mojibake

I hope you are all well. I have an Excel sheet that contains Cyrillic alphabet. I would like to get it to English/Latin Is there any easy way that Excel can do this? Thank you in advance for the help.

[image]

Comment: I think you need `transliteration`, https://superuser.com/questions/593082/batch-transliterate-excel-xlsx-files

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows **no [Cyrillic letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_alphabets#Common_letters)**: those would look like e.g. the Ukrainian alphabet letters: `А а Б б В в Г г Ґ ґ Д д Е е Є є Ж ж З з И и І і Ї ї Й й К к Л л М м Н н О о П п Р р С с Т т У у Ф ф Х х Ц ц Ч ч Ш ш Щ щ Ь ь Ю ю Я я`

You are victim of flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case rather as shown in next example; `39142772.txt` file contains some accented characters (all *Central Europe Latin*). The file based on lines 1, 10 and 23 of your data, retyped to Czech and Hungarian valid names and is saved with *UTF-8* encoding:

```
==> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

==> type D:\test\39142772.txt

 1 STÁTNÍ ÚSTAV PRO KONTROLU LÉČIV
10 Pikó, Béla
23 Móricz, István

==> chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

==> type D:\test\39142772.txt

 1 STÃTNÃ ÃšSTAV PRO KONTROLU LÃ‰ÄŒIV
10 PikÃ³, BÃ©la
23 MÃ³ricz, IstvÃ¡n

==>
```

**Explanation**: [`chcp` command](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) changes the active console Code Page;

- `chcp 65001` (*UTF-8*): file is displayed properly;
- `chcp 1252` (*West European Latin*): accented characters in file are displayed *mojibake* transformed exactly as shown in your screenshot;
- the same *mojibake* transformation would happen if you import a `.txt` or `.csv` file into Excel using wrong encoding.

**Solution**: import a `.txt` or `.csv` file into Excel using proper encoding. Procedure is described here: [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488070/3439404).