# Import CSV to Excel matching column header using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv, header

I want to ask if how can I achieve importing CSV file to my Excel file matching the columns of my template using macro (or VBA).

Here's why I'm frustrated to ask this question. I searched for answer. Google didn't help. No one is asking for this type of question.

I have a file name "UserInfo.xlsx" which has a column headers:

- UserID
- Username
- Name
- ContactNumber
- EmailAddress
- LastLogin

Now I have a CSV file (generated by our website) with some excess headers which I don't need.

The headers from my CSV file and headers from my template are exactly the same. The problem is I want to get those information based on their column headers (CSV) that will match the template's header.

How can I achieve this? I will use this template everyday because new users are signing up to our website. So I need a VBA code for this.

I don't know where to start so I'm asking for your help.

Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the csv file with an ADODB.Connection. If you have over 65K record then CopyFromRecordset probably won't work and you'll have to use ADODB.Recordset.GetRows to retrieve the data.

```
Sub Example()
On Error Resume Next
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Dim conn As Object, rs As Object
Dim Filename As String, FilePath As String

FilePath = "C:\"
Filename = "UserInfo.csv"

'Refernce: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx
'Excel VBA Introduction Part 30 - ADO (ActiveX Data Objects) Querying a Database: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HE9CIbetNnI&index=33&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & FilePath & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

rs.Open "SELECT [UserID],[Username],[Name],[ContactNumber],[EmailAddress],[LastLogin] FROM [" & Filename & "]", _
        conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
conn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Can I ask how to use ADODB.Recordset.GetRows?

Comment: I created an example workbook: [Download Example Workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByjAVr__2CigOEhHVWhmemJVUjQ)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works like a charm! Although I change it a little bit since I'm using Windows 10 and I think Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 doesn't work with my current Excel version (2016).

I changed **Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0** to **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0**

I also found out that the FilePath variable is wrong. I removed the filename which is UserInfo.csv and I was shocked when I tried running it. Works as expected.

Since I don't have enough points to post a screenshot, I can say that your code really and I mean really works!

Thank you so much.

Here's my final code:

```
Sub Example()
On Error Resume Next
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Dim conn As Object, rs As Object
Dim Filename As String, FilePath As String

FilePath = "C:\" 'Just remove the filename and extension
Filename = "UserInfo.csv"

'Refernce: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx
'Excel VBA Introduction Part 30 - ADO (ActiveX Data Objects) Querying a Database: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HE9CIbetNnI&index=33&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & FilePath & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""" 'Change the Provider

rs.Open "SELECT [UserID],[Username],[Name],[ContactNumber],[EmailAddress],[LastLogin] FROM [" & Filename & "]", _
        conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
conn.Close
End Sub
```

Again thank you so much Thomas Inzina. You have just saved my life. :)

Comment: I have a question Thomas. Is it possible to import my CSV files in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: The excepted answer to this post shows you how: [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically) You could record a macro to find out the steps. Can you provide me a sample csv file?

Comment: Another question. I know this is kinda off-topic but how can I stop Excel converting a data into numbers. Example, the usercode is 0008, Excel automatically converts it into 8 literally. Or should I ask how to stop excel removing the preceding zeros and treat it as a normal string?

Comment: You can format the cells as text.  If all the ID's have 4 characters you can use a custom NumberFormat format e.g. if `[A1].NumberFormat = "0000"` then if `[A1] = 8`  then `[A1].Value` would equal `8` and `[A1].Text` would = `0008`.

Answer (score 0):

[Contextures Excel Sample Data](http://www.contextures.com/xlSampleData01.html)

I would record a macro importing your file using these steps: [How to import a .csv file that uses UTF-8 character encoding](https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0).  You should be able to easily customize the recorded macro to fit your needs.

**Note:** When importing CSV files Excel allows you to skip columns.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I already found an answer and it works fine.

Comment: I add CharacterSet=65001 to my connection string.
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
              "Data Source=" & FilePath & ";" & _
              "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(,);CharacterSet=65001'"

Comment: Another question (sorry for too much questions hehehe)
Is it possible to scan first the file before putting it to the designated sheet?
I mean it will first read the column row by row. If detected a number with preceeding zeros or any number, automatically it will add semicolon in front of that number.

Is it possible? I wonder how to do that.

Comment: A CSV file is just a text file.  There are several ways to read and write to it.  But if you add delimiters you will through off the columns.

Comment: Oopss. Hahaha sorry. Maybe because I often use OpenOffice to open CSV files. Hahahaha.