# Writing unicode to csv in Python and opening with MS Excel

Tags: python-2.7, csv, python-unicode

I'm writing small app to compare two XML files and then output differences to CSV. All looks fine when I open CSV with notepad++ (shows encoding UTF-8 but I get weird characters when opening with MS Excel. Any ideas how to make it work in MS Excel too?

I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse XML files. Differences are stored in two lists. I've tried all kind of suggestions from other similar questions but nothing seems to work.

File saving code is here:

```
def saveresults():
filesave = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=filenewdir, title="Save to CSV",
                                      defaultextension=".csv", filetypes=[("CSV (Comma delimited)", ".csv")])
if filesave is not None:
    with open(filesave, 'wb') as fp:
        writef = unicodecsv.writer(fp, dialect="excel-tab", encoding="utf-8")
        writef.writerow(("Trigger", "Variable", "Old label", "Old columns", "Old precode", "Old precode text",
                        "New label", "New columns", "New precode", "New precode text"))

        for x, newvalue in enumerate(newvalues):
            writef.writerow((newvalue[0], newvalue[1], oldvalues[x][2], oldvalues[x][3], oldvalues[x][4],
                             oldvalues[x][5], newvalue[2], newvalue[3], newvalue[4], newvalue[5]))
        fp.close()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Message", message="Done!")
```

Tested Text in notepad:

Spend £2,000 or more on building, dcorating or home improvements Lietuvos valstiečių ir žaliųjų sąjungos (LVŽS)

Same text when opened with MS Excel:

Spend Â£2,000 or more on building, dcorating or home improvements Lietuvos valstieÄiÅ³ ir Å¾aliÅ³jÅ³ sÄ…jungos (LVÅ½S)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the MS Excel version is reading the file as if it was encoded in ANSI, so I expect this is an excel problem in the end - you mention trying ideas from other questions, does that include [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically) ? In particular does it work if you open excel then import the data, rather than opening the data with excel from explorer/command line?

Comment: It works in Excel if I import CSV using wizard or convert encoding to UTF-8 with BOM in notepad before opening it.

Would be the right way to add BOM? I tried `writef.writerow(codecs.BOM_UTF8)` but it didn't work.

Comment: You can try explicitly including the BOM:
`writerow('\uefbbbf')`
but that's formally not recommended - probably hence why it's not done automatically