# Add byte order mark to CSV parsed via PapaParse

Tags: javascript, json, excel, csv, papaparse

I'm using [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com/) in my application that converts JSON data to CSV then downloads it for the user. The problem is that my data is encoded in UTF-8 so when I open up the exported in Excel (without going through the text wizard), it assumes ASCII.

I found a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11399444) that suggests using a byte order mark and was curious on the correct way of adding this so that Excel recognizes the UTF-8 encoding.

Apologies for not having any codes samples, I'm not even quite sure where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-export-as-excel-csv/1191/25

I simply prepended the BOM to the beginning of the CSV text string