# How to open a text file with Excel in UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: excel, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a text file with ".tsv" extension.
It has UTF-8 enconding and it contains cyrillic characters.
When I try to open it with the function: "Open with"-> "Excel", Excel doesn't show the correct characters, while if I open it with Notepad++ in the same way, I can see characters correctly.
I would like to avoid importing the file in Excel with the wizard.

Comment: Can you supply a few lines of the TSV file?

Comment: try changing the extension .TSV to .TXT or .CSV and try to open it with Excel

Comment: I would like to avoid renaming the extension in txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Comment: I couldn't get tsv+utf8 to work (didn't want [to mess with the registry](https://superuser.com/a/1179248/10136)), but [tsv in the "UTF-16LE with BOM" encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically#comment29577183_6002256) does work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use Data, Get External Data, From Text and supply the proper encoding for the File Origin.

[image]

Comment: I would like to avoid importing the file in Excel with the wizard.

Comment: Then record yourself doing this and rerun the recorded sub procedure whenever you need to reimport.

Comment: I have tried to do that but it didn't store the choice. My goal is associate the extention to Excel and open all file tsv with UTF-8 enconding.

Comment: I've created a program meant to be the file handler for CSV files that will modify the file for Excel to recognize the encoding then pass it over to Excel to open. Just solving the problem for myself, but would love suggestions/PRs to improve the project for a wider audience. https://github.com/indepndnt/utf8csv