# I am getting japanese characters as Junk while converting csv to Excel using Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Macro scripts,
I am trying to convert a Csv file to excel, which contains japnese characters.
After conversion excel is not holding right format.
could you please suggets me how to encode excel to UTF-8 while conversion from csv to excel.

**below is my Macro code.**

```
Sub Csv2Excel()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strFile As String, strDir As String

strDir = "D:\DH\testFile\EQT_OFFER_DATA_0000567\"
strFile = Dir(strDir & "EQT_OFFER_DATA_0000567.csv")

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strDir & strFile)
    ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.Encoding = msoEncodingUTF8
    With wb
        .SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".csv", ".xlsx"), 51 'UPDATE:
        .Close True
    End With
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Csv file content**
`xxxxxxx","1298153","xxxxxx","本多　周二","大阪府 富田林市 梅の里 1丁目 18ｰ5","Individual`

**Out out Excel**
`xxxxxxx    1298153 xxxxxx  æœ¬å¤šã€€å‘¨äºŒ å¤§é˜ªåºœ å¯Œç”°æž—å¸‚ æ¢…ã®é‡Œ 1ä¸ç›® 18ï½°5   Individual`

Please guide me.

Comment: What encoding does your CSV file have?

Comment: csv File have UTF-8

Comment: Try [worlbooks.opentext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/opentextfile-method?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with iomode:=TristateTrue for unicode or data, get data, from text and choose the utf-8 language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a text file with Excel in UTF-8 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307776/how-to-open-a-text-file-with-excel-in-utf-8-encoding/43308865#43308865).

Comment: I have tried to use  `Set wb = Workbooks.OpenText(strDir & strFile, ForReading, TristateTrue)` but it is throwing compilation error

Comment: You can't call a function in VBA like this with `()`. See my answer below.

Comment: I have recorded macro using get data ad using utf-8 language, it has worked fine

Answer (score 1):

To open Unicode files, try using OpenText method instead of Open:

```
Workbooks.OpenText filename:=strDir & strFile, origin:=65001, DataType:=xlDelimited, textqualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, comma:=True
```

For the complete list of codepage numbers (`origin` parameter) see this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks for  answer, Still japanese characters are coming as junk.

Comment: It's quite strange, I guess your source file is not UTF-8 then.