# Spanish special characters not displaying properly in Excel on Windows works on linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, encoding, utf-8

I have spanish data in my oracle database (charectorset AL32UTF8). I am reading the data from the db and writing into a `csv` file, and from `csv` I am reading the data again and doing some operation. But in the `csv` file it is displaying junk values.

I did the same thing on linux and it is working correctly.

```
public class T {

    CSVWriter out = null;

    private void write(String[] values) throws IOException {
        out.writeNext(values);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File f  = new File("s.csv");

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f, false);

        CSVWriter out = new CSVWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(
                    os, "UTF-8")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the encoding?

Comment: post code how you are reading

Comment: Hmm, I guess, the system char set on Windows (that's what EXCEL uses to read the CSV file) is not UTF-8.

Comment: you are saying linux characterset is utf8 so it is working on linux ?

Comment: @Henry  is utf8 default encoding for linux?. how do i say excel to open file in utf8? I tried to specify BOM also

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell Excel to use the correct encoding when opening the CSV file

see below:

[Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Comment: I dont want to do it manually, java should read the excel correctly.

Comment: From the code, I see that you are correctly using UTF-8 when creating the csv file.  Then it is only missing to use "UTF-8" when opening/reading  the CSV file in Java.    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(
                      new FileInputStream("your CSV file goes here"), "UTF8"));