# Thai characters not shown correctly while spooling csv using sqlplus and opening in ms-excel?

Tags: csv, unix, character-encoding, sqlplus, spool

I am spooling csv from sqlplus database in unix os have some Thai characters. After spooling when i am opening csv using ms-excel it is giving me some different encoding characters. The spooled file is UTF-8 format.While opening file using open text/csv and change encoding to 65001(Utf-8) it is working fine.I also added BOM(Byte of mark) character but it didn't work fine.Please suggest any solution to open csv directly in excel without using open text/csv to get correct output with thai characters.

Comment: Try adding Byte Order Mark `FE FF` (actually UTF-16BE) since the data comes from unix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Comment: @Theo That's the right tip but the wrong encoding: EF BB BF (UTF-8)

Comment: @TomBlodget The OP already tried the UTF-8 BOM From other posts I learned that csv created from Unix systems better use the UTF-16BE encoding with BOM for Excel to read them properly. Let's see what works for the OP.

Comment: @TomBlodget NO, please leave your comment because technically it is correct and the BOM for UTF-8 is `EF BB BF` as you say. In this case however, I'm curious to hear from the OP what worked.