# Excel CSV output appearing wrong after calling Python File

Tags: python, excel, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

Currently struggling with the following output in .csv where their is various random character within the is the players names and values where there shouldn't be

**(I've given a picture below of the output)**

I'm wondering where I'm going wrong in the code where I'm struggling to eliminate the random characters

**I'm trying to remove the characters below such as Â, Ã, ©, ‰ and so on.
Any suggestions?**

**Python Code**

```
#importing

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

#calling websites
page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik/top/plus/0/galerie/0?saison_id=2000"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

#calling players names
Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
#Let's look at the first name in the Players list.
Players[0].text

#calling value of players
Values = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})
#Let's look at the first name in the Values list.
Values[0].text

PlayersList = []
ValuesList = []

for i in range(0,25):
   PlayersList.append(Players[i].text)
   ValuesList.append(Values[i].text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":PlayersList,"Values":ValuesList})

df.to_csv('2000.csv', index=False)

df.head()
```

====================================================================

**My Excel output**

[image: The Output]

Comment: Have you tried `pageTree.text` instead of `pageTree.content` so that the encoding is automatically handled? Might find that'll sort everything out for you.

Comment: Those characters are clearly UTF-8 characters (like é => Ã©) seen from an ISO-8859-1 or Windows codepage 1252 context. The output is probably correct, it's the system you are viewing it from that is not set to UTF-8.

Comment: oh, I have to correct myself. The problem is Excel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically

Comment: @JonClements Hey Jon, tried it out and it doesn't change the characters

Comment: @WalterTross thank you for the link, I changed the encoding in excel after importing and worked

Comment: @Kevin might just want to use `df.to_excel(...)` directly if you don't require CSVs... that way you also get nice goodies such as types preserved and other formatting etc...

Comment: @Kevin I cannot try out my solution right now, but I'm pretty sure it works. Have you tried it out?

Comment: @WalterTross Hi Walter, Yes it working perfectly now. Many Thanks

Comment: @KevinCarmody IF what is working now is the code suggested by my answer, may I ask you to accept it? Upvoting and accepting is what makes StackOverflow tick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...
utf8_bom = '\xEF\xBB\xBF'
with open('2000.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(utf8_bom)
    df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, mode='a')
```

Explanation: The BOM is the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (q.v.). If Excel finds it at the beginning of the CSV file, it uses it to determine the encoding, which in your case is UTF-8 (the default encoding – correctly – for Python 3).

---

**EDIT**

As Mark Tolonen pointed out, the compact version of the above is the following code:

```
df.to_csv('2000.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

The `-sig` in the name of the encoding stands for “signature”, i.e., the BOM at the beginning which is used by Microsoft software to detect the encoding. See also the [Encodings and Unicode](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode) section of the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) manual.

Comment: Or just `df.to_csv('2000.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)` :^)

Answer (score 2):

You system seems to be writing the file encoded as UTF-8.  Excel expects UTF-8 files to have a BOM signature, else it assumes a text file is encoded in a locale-specific ANSI encoding.  This is for backward compatibility due to Windows existing before UTF-8 did.

Python has an encoding that writes the UTF-8 BOM signature, `utf-8-sig`, so simply use:

```
df.to_csv('2000.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I've fixed this situation from the following answer in the link below..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488070/10675615

> 1. Save the exported file as a csv in the cmd prompt
> 2. Open Excel
> 3. Import the data using Data-->Import External Data/ Get Text/CSV --> Import Data
> 4. Select the file type of "csv" and browse to your file
> 5. In the import wizard change the File_Origin to "65001 UTF" (or choose the correct language character identifier)
> 6. Change the Delimiter to comma
> 7. Select where to import to and Finish This way the special characters should show correctly.

**