# Is it possible to write csv in r where data is cleaned with UTF-8 characters?

Tags: r

Initial csv file is having Thai Language in some columns, i have queried the data from SQL server and save as csv-utf8 format, so csv itself having thai language, while loading in r, Successfully read the data in Thai in R, after cleaning the data, is it possible to store the Thai in csv

In First R Script I set the environment and read the csv.
After Data Cleaning, tried writing csv in the R Scripts shown below, but the result csv is not having Thai instead having other characters

```
Sys.setlocale(locale="Thai")
data <- read.csv("data.csv",encoding = "UTF-8")
```

```
write.csv(data,"data.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

```
encodeConnection <- file('data.csv', encoding = "UTF-8")
write.csv(data, file = encodeConnection)
```

```
readr::write_csv(data,"data.csv")
data.table::fwrite(data,"data.csv")
```

I expect csv with Thai, but having "à¸šà¸±à¸•à¸£à¸›à¸£à¸°à¸Šà¸²à¸Šà¸™"

Comment: Are you sure that the issue isn't with the program used to view the output file?

Comment: Just opening the csv via excel as did for opening after queried from SQL server

Comment: Excel doesn't necessarily automatically recognise UTF-8 encoding for csv files - use the data import wizard so you can specify the encoding.

Comment: may i know what is that data import wizard pls

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488070/2835261

Comment: sure, thanks for that, will try that

Comment: That worked, great, Thanks