# Encoding foreign language

Tags: excel, encoding

I have an Excel-CSV file contains a foreign language. Originally, it looks like this:

```
!Ð¯ÐºÑƒÑ‚ÑÐº Ð¢Ð¦ "Ð¦ÐµÐ½Ñ‚Ñ€Ð°Ð»ÑŒÐ½Ñ‹Ð¹" Ñ„Ñ€Ð°Ð½,1
```

There is the possibility to encode the text by `65001 unicode (utf-8)`

After the encoding, the text looks like this:

```
!Якутск Орджоникидзе, 56 фран,0
```

However. if I save the file and open it again it looks like this:

```
!?????? ????????????, 56 ????,0
```

How can I keep the encoding which I did by `65001 unicode (utf-8)`?

Comment: Excel naturally stores data in Unicode. Are you sure it is an Excel file (and not e.g. a CSV file)?

Comment: Yes, it´s an Excel-CSV.

Comment: Hi, does this solve the issue? https://help.surveygizmo.com/help/encode-an-excel-file-to-utf-8-or-utf-16

Comment: If you just have one `.csv` why don't you save it using `UTF-8` coding when you open it through Notepad?

Comment: There is no such thing as Excel-CSV. There is CSV, which Excel can read (and often associates itself with, giving it an Excel icon). The file itself has nothing to do with Excel though. First I would try saving the file as UTF-16. If that is not an option and you want to keep UTF-8, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6002256/11683.

Comment: You write `save the file and open`, **save** it as what?  **open** it with what program?