# Is there any way to open a csv file that contains arabic, in excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, scrapy, libreoffice

I have created a csv file using python, that contains Arabic lines I scraped from a website and its showing as it is in ubuntu libreoffice. But when I try to open it in MS Excel it shows garbage values

Libreoffice (Perfectly allright)

```
س کی مثال بیج کی سی
```

Excel (Garbage Values)

```
 Ø¹Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù† Ø¸ÙØ± ÛØ±Ù† Ù¾Ù
```

Is there any way of getting same value as of Libreoffice in excel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488070/7306999

Comment: Is there a need for the `python` and `libreoffice` tags here? I don’t see any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from https://help.livehelpnow.net/1/article/45188/viewing-exported-csv-files-containing-arabic-characters

```
1. Save the exported file as a csv
2. Open Excel
3. Import the data using Data-->Import External Data --> Import Data
4. Select the file type of "csv" and browse to your file
4. In the import wizard change the File_Origin to "65001 UTF" (or choose correct language character identifier)
5. Change the Delimiter to comma
6. Select where to import to and Finish
```