# Cannot show diacritics in exported CSV file

Tags: javascript, excel

I wrote a js code that exported data into .csv table. My problem is that when I  open the file Excel cannot show Czech diacritics like č or š. Anyone can help me?

```js
function exportData(){
                console.log("Started export to CSV.");

                const rows = [
                    ["Procesor" +  "      " +  String(window.localStorage.getItem("CPU"))],
                    ["RAM" + "      " + String(window.localStorage.getItem("RAM"))],
                    ["Displej" +  "      " +  String(window.localStorage.getItem("display"))],
                    ["Baterie" +  "      " +  String(window.localStorage.getItem("battery"))],
                    ["Grafická karta" +  "      " +  String(window.localStorage.getItem("GPU"))],
                ];

                let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," 
                    + rows.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n");

                var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
                link.setAttribute("download", "parametry.csv");
                document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

                link.click(); // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv".
            }`
```

Comment: If you add a BOM to the csv file, Excel will realize it is UTF8 code and you'll be able to **Open** the file. Otherwise, you'll need to **Import** the file at which time you can tell excel the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

On my mac, the UTF-8 CSV gets displayed properly, so this is a bug in Excel.

There's a similar question on SO that might be of interest to you, but here's a summary:

1. Open Excel
2. Import the data using Data-->Import External Data --> Import Data
3. Select the file type of "csv" and browse to your file
4. In the import wizard change the File_Origin to "65001 UTF" (or choose correct language character identifier)
5. Change the Delimiter to comma
6. Select where to import to and Finish

Credit to original answer: [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)