# How to save special characters in a csv while preserving them for excel?

Tags: r, excel, csv

Let's consider this simple creation of a csv file with a dataframe that contains special characters:

```
d <- data.frame(x = "Édifice", y="Arrêt")
write.table(x = d, file = "test.csv", sep = ",", row.names = F, col.names = F, quote = F, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

The csv file looks like expected

```
Édifice,Arrêt
```

But when I open this csv in excel I get:

[image: excel]

I have tried using readr, collapsing columns and then writing them with writeLines, writing using write.xlsx, checked for encoding options. None worked.

My constraint is that the input is a dataframe, and the output must be a csv readable in excel.

Comment: R produces your CSV just fine---it seems the issue is how to open a UTF-8 encoded CSV in Excel.

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [Is it possible to force Excel to recognize UTF-8 CSVs automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6002256/903061)

Comment: Though, inspired by some of the answers there, you could potentially try saving the file in UTF-16 encoding or adding a BOM as descibed in `?file`

Answer (score 3):

Same problem with german umlaute. I use `write_excel_csv` from `readr`:

```
library(readr)
write_excel_csv(x = d, path = "test.csv", col_names = F)
```