# Microsoft Excel added special character in CSV file

Tags: java, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have .xlxs and .csv file of same content with text - **Valbuena 5.°**
The problem is when I open .csv file in Micrsoft Excel, it add one special character like -
**Valbuena 5.Â°**

I am creating both file in Java with UTF_8 character set.

Any solution will be appciciable.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I guess the encoding is correct and the problem isn't your code.

The fact is Excel isn't encoding in UTF-8 by default. If you want to retrieve your encoding, you must

1. Open excel (new file)
2. Data menu
3. From text
4. Select your file, choose UTF-8 encoding and you will see the right text

The best solution is to change your default excel encoding, i'm not sure if it's possible but I link a workaround :[Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)