# When creating a csv file in javascript I can't get my åäö to show in the file

Tags: javascript, csv

```
                var encodedUri =  encodeURI( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + response.data);
                
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
                if(!this.filter.periodFromLastSearch && !this.filter.periodToLastSearch)
                {
                    link.setAttribute("download", `review.csv`);
                }
                else{
                    link.setAttribute("download", `review${this.filter.periodFromLastSearch.replace(/-/g,'')}-${this.filter.periodToLastSearch.replace(/-/g,'')}.csv`);
                }
                document.body.appendChild(link); 
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
```

This is the way I create my csv file but when having characters like "åäö" I can't seem to get them into the actual file. I have tried using the respective codes \u00F6 in the string before encodeURI is done and after.

Anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Replacing `response.data` with the literal `"åäö"` works for me.

Comment: I've tried doing
response.data = response.data.replace('BalanceChange','Nettof\u00F6r\u00E4ndring');
but doesn't solve it. Still NettofÃ¶rÃ¤ndring in the excel when I open it

Comment: How do you open the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)