# Can't open exported Excel file due to problematic text string

Tags: r, character-encoding, writexl

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(QB5B_2 = structure("Car les GAFA sont des sociétés Américaines et de plus les gouvernements qui composent l'Union Européenne ne sont pas d'accord entre elles sur la stratégie à adopter en ce qui les concerne . Exemple les Gafa payent des impots en Irlande car leurs si<ef>", label = "test", format.spss = "A255", display_width = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

When I look at this data in RStudios View pane, it looks like proper French text:

`View(problem)` shows:

[image]

However, when looking at the data in the console it gives me:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  QB5B_2                                                                                                                 
  <chr>                                                                                                                  
1 "Car les GAFA sont des soci\xc3\xa9t\xc3\xa9s Am\xc3\xa9ricaines et de plus les gouvernements qui composent l'Union Eu~
```

So it's clear there is some character encoding problem.

Now, when I try to export the file to Excel with:

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(problem, "test.xlsx")
```

it does the exporting but I can't open the file in Excel and instead get an error message that a problem has been encountered. Side note: I can import the Excel file perfectly fine with e.g. `readxl::read_xlsx("test.xlsx")`

So two questions:

- How can I prevent these character issues in the first place? Ideally I wouldn't get these weird `\xc3\` things in the data.
- Is there any way to export the file so that it can be opened properly in Excel?

Comment: The \xc3 is part of the encoding of the UTF-8 characters. Do you have encoding set during the import of the file by `encoding = "UTF-8"`?  [See here.](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

Comment: Good question. I'm colelcting my data through an API, but I guess teh default would be UTF-8 encoding, yes. But I always though UTF-8 is sth. good and shoudl be handled by all software tools, so I would expect Excel to be able to open such characters?

Comment: Actually after downloading the data through API via `httr:POST` I have the following line of code: `download_content <- content(download_request, encoding = "UTF-8")`

Comment: (but leaving the "encoding = UTF-8" part out, doesn't change anything in the data (just tried).

Comment: It looks to me like the problem doesn't lie with R. It takes the special character and properly does the UTF-8 encoding according to the data table of special characters. It is a question of how the data is exported to Excel. So the goal is not to 'get rid' of the weird characters/codes. They are correct. It's why does Excel not take it. I don't know much about Excel, but is there maybe an option to import UTF-8 specifically (unless that's the default as well)?

Comment: When copy-pasting this definition of `structure()` on my computer it displays correctly in the console, and I can save it to Excel which opens with the proper accents. That's on a US Windows. So I do think the problem is at the API and R steps, not Excel.

Comment: OK, with your structure, `Encoding(problem$QB5B_2)` is latin1, I can reproduce your problem with `Encoding(problem$QB5B_2) <- "UTF-8"`, and solve it back by setting `Encoding() <- "latin1"`. I suspect the text was actually Latin1, but the API is just pretending it's UTF-8 without converting.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with Excel and UTF-8 encoding. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is quite strange since your input shows a double quote before the text, which usually does not happen when displaying the content of a character-column in a tibble. Look right after the "1":

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
 QB5B_2                                                                                                                 
 <chr>                                                                                                                  
1 "Car les GAFA sont des soci\xc3\xa9t\xc3\xa9s Am\xc3\xa9ricaines et de plus les gouvernements qui composent l'Union Eu~
```

Perhaps a solution is to reencode the variable using `iconv()`:

```
problem$QB5B_2 <- iconv(problem$QB5B_2, sub = "byte")
problem
# A tibble: 1 x 1
   QB5B_2                                                                                                                
   <chr>                                                                                                                 
1 Car les GAFA sont des sociétés Américaines et de plus les gouvernements qui composent l'Union Européenne ne sont pas …
```

Another would be to remove the first character:

```
problem$QB5B_2 <- str_remove(problem$QB5B_2, pattern = "$.")
problem
# A tibble: 1 x 1
   QB5B_2                                                                                                                
   <chr>                                                                                                                 
1 Car les GAFA sont des sociétés Américaines et de plus les gouvernements qui composent l'Union Européenne ne sont pas …
```

This does not show how to avoid the issue in the first place, but it should sort you out.

One difficulty in doing the debugging here is that `dput()`, which you probably used to replicate the content does not keep the problem...

Comment: Incredible, the second solution you provided did solve the problem for me. I'm still not sure how and where the issue occured, but I got it fixed at least for this example.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the text is actually encoded as latin1, but the encoding is set to UTF-8. So R tries to read the latin1 as if it was UTF-8 and gets it wrong.

```
# by default, R used latin1
> Encoding(problem$QB5B_2)
[1] "latin1"

# in that case, no problem to display it
> problem
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  QB5B_2                                                                          
  <chr>                                                                           
1 Car les GAFA sont des sociétés Américaines et de plus les gouvernements qui com~

# But the API set it as UTF-8
> Encoding(problem$QB5B_2) <- "UTF-8"
> problem
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  QB5B_2                                                                          
  <chr>                                                                           
1 Car les GAFA sont des soci\xe9t\xe9s Am\xe9ricaines et de plus les gouvernemen~

# You just need to convert the encoding back
> Encoding(problem$QB5B_2) <- "latin1"
> problem
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  QB5B_2                                                                          
  <chr>                                                                           
1 Car les GAFA sont des sociétés Américaines et de plus les gouvernements qui com~
```

See also the first example in `?Encoding` which is very similar. On a French computer, the locale would be set to `latin1` and you can use `enc2native()`.