# Csv File Doesn't Show German Characters After Downloading via .Net Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, csv, encoding, csvhelper

I have to return a csv file template which has some columns with german characters in my one of my api enpoint.

This is the simplified version of endpoint:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Stream), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [Route("template")]
    public async Task GetTemplate()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.Headers.AddContentDispositionAttachment("Template.csv");

        CsvConfiguration csvConfiguration = new (new CultureInfo("de-de"))
        {
            Delimiter = ";",
            HasHeaderRecord = false
        };

        string header = $"Url;Beschreibung;Code;ID;Löschen;Straße;Pünklitch";

        using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(Response.Body, Encoding.UTF8, 65536);
        await using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, csvConfiguration);
        await streamWriter.WriteAsync(header);
    }
```

It is pretty straight forward.

The problem is; when I call endpoint via swagger in local or on server  and download the file *it doesn't show german characters properly*. Also when I entagrate endpoint to my Front end and download file via ui it also behave as same way and doesn't show german characters. But when I *call the endpoint from browser directly everything looks ok*.

This is how csv file looks after download:

[image]

Any idea ? How can I fix encoding problem?

I am using .net framwork 6

Comment: What you see in Excel depends how you import the file into Excel. If it looks wrong in Excel that does not mean your code is wrong. But you could try adding `Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: @KlausGütter there is no ContentEncoding property in HttpResponse. Any equvalent ?

Comment: If you open it in notepad?

Comment: @Magnus it looks open in notepad++.

Comment: this is not an encoding issue.  You just need to switch to a Font that contains the German characters.

Comment: It looks open? What does that mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Comment: Also, it's "Pünktlich". not "Pünklitch" :)

Comment: @Magnus sorry, it should be 'it looks ok'

Comment: @NineBerry thanks for link but I checked this before but I couldn't figure out the solution. And thanks for typo warning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you open a CSV file by double clicking on it to open it in Excel, Excel assumes the file is in an older Windows encoding, rather than UTF8.  You have two options:

1. Force a Byte Order Mark (BOM) at the beginning of the file for UTF8.  Most newer versions of Excel will recognize the BOM and open it as UTF8 instead of the older encoding. There are some versions of Excel, however, that will ignore the BOM.  (FYI your code is not using the `csvWriter`, but this should still work when you do output with `csvWriter` rather than `streamWriter` directly.)

```cs
using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(Response.Body, Encoding.UTF8, 65536);
using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, csvConfiguration);

var preamble = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
await streamWriter.BaseStream.WriteAsync(preamble, 0, preamble.Length);

await streamWriter.WriteAsync(header);
```

2. Use the older Windows encoding instead of UTF8. This should work as long as you only have German characters and not other UTF8 characters that won't convert. I'm not certain what it would be in Germany, but I'm going to guess it is Windows-1252.

```cs
using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(Response.Body, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), 65536);

// Or you might need to use iso-8859-1
using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(Response.Body, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), 65536);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a custom Ascii converter which will replace all your chars with an ascii symbol.  for example you could use `Dictionary<string, string>` and map each char to it's ascii

```
private Dictionary<string, string> CharToASCII = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"Ö",  @"\'d6"},
    {"ö",  @"\'f6"}
    }
```

then you can just call a function with your string as an input parameter and as a result you will have an ascii written instead of German letters

```
   public string ConvertToAscii(string myString)
        {

            var res = CharToASCII.Aggregate(myString, (current, value) =>
                current.Replace(value.Key, value.Value));


            return res;
        }
```