# Does Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() create a BOM?

Tags: c#, encoding, byte-order-mark

I'm making an HTTP POST request with this:

```
byte[] postBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postStr);
```

So far, this seems working fine but I'm not sure if this will always work, because **Encoding.UTF8** means UTF8 WITH BOM. When I create local files with `StreamWriter`, always use the default encoding which is the same as **new UTF8Encoding(false)** in order to write WITHOUT BOM. So wonder if the same is true for calling `GetBytes()` method too.

In this case, isn't there any difference between above and below line?

```
byte[] postBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(postStr);
```

I tested several times myself but still not sure 100%, so asking here.

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414118/2395747

Comment: That's not what it means.  On Windows a BOM is pretty important for a file to make apps that don't know anything about the file still interpret it correctly.  Just not the case for a network protocol since both ends need to agree about the stream content.  And for http the header dictates the encoding.  You'd rely on, say, HttpWebResponse.ContentEncoding

Comment: @wmioduszewski Thanks, that answer also helped!

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you thank you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `GetBytes` method never returns a stream of bytes prefaced with a BOM. 
The BOM can be retrieve by using the `GetPreAmble` method, which returns nothing when the encoder is instantiated with false.

See the extensive Remarks section on [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding) for more details.