BOM Merging Excel columns while working on CSV C#
I am working on a CSV file where a user will download a template which contains header field and after that user will enter the data into the csv and save the csv after that upload the csv into the system.
it was working fine until one of our client informed us to add Arabic support into the csv.
our historical code looked like below
byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("prefilled data, Header Data 1, Header Data 2\n abc");//not an actual code as I changed this code few weeks back
return File(fileBytes, "text/csv", Path.GetFileName(data.FilePath));

after the request we have updated our to something like below
byte[] csvBytes = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("prefilled data, Header Data 1, Header Data 2\n رخصة تجارية");
return File(csvBytes, "text/tsv", fileName.Replace(".csv", ".tsv"));

but even this was not working Screenshot for your reference. 
after some google search and a help from chatGPT I come to know that Excel is not recognizing the file as utf-8 and I should use BOM to help excel to recognize the file as UTF-8.
after that I did the below code with the help of chatGPT.
byte[] utf8Bom = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetPreamble(); // `true` to add BOM
byte[] csvBytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("prefilled data, Header Data 1, Header Data 2\n رخصة تجارية");

byte[] resultBytes = new byte[utf8Bom.Length + csvBytes.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(utf8Bom, 0, resultBytes, 0, utf8Bom.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(csvBytes, 0, resultBytes, utf8Bom.Length, csvBytes.Length);

return File(resultBytes, "text/csv", fileName);

after this the excel is now able to handle arabic text but the problem is when I fill all the data and save it and open the file again it is merging all the column into one and I open the data again in notepad++ the "," is replaced automatically with "    " (tab).
how to fix this.

File.ReadAllBytes accepts a file path, your historical code is wrong, please don't provide fake code.

@shingo you are write. changed my code a bit. I was in a hurry hence this happened

According to this article, there's nothing to do with C#, this is an issue with Excel. You need Excel 2019 or higher version and save the file as CSV UTF-8 format.

@shingo but the same is working on excel 2007 Version

Then why not use Excel 2007 to edit?

the application is deployed to multiple clients and we can't ask them to use different version of excel

so this solution seems to fix this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30839531/11327476
